# Wildfly16 setting up embedded Artemis with mqtt support

Tags: wildfly, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I am trying to set up wildfly16 with embedded Artemis with support for mqtt.

These are my config files

I have been able to publish messages to jms-topic jms/topic/test1 from JMS java client and MQTT java client. I have been able to sent messages from Jmetter by means of a mqtt publisher sampler.

I have been able to receive the messages from JMS java client however it has been impossible to subscribe to the topic jms/topic/test1 from any mqtt client Java client with paho library,
MQTTBox or Jmeter.

The Java client connect but raise an exception when subscribing  "Se ha perdido la conexión (32109) - java.io.EOFException"

So I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

My wildfly running

```
16:15:24,632 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
16:15:24,621 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
16:15:24,890 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
16:15:24,890 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
16:15:24,891 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
16:15:24,891 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
16:15:24,891 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
16:15:24,940 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.7) 
16:15:25,056 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
16:15:25,056 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
16:15:25,838 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
16:15:25,842 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
16:15:25,843 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
16:15:25,838 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
16:15:26,081 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 127.0.0.1:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
16:15:26,121 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221007: Server is now live
16:15:26,121 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.6.3.jbossorg-00014 [default, nodeID=b81df2c8-5d5e-11e9-a53d-14dae99243d9] 
16:15:26,139 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
16:15:26,242 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test
16:15:26,243 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test
16:15:26,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
16:15:26,313 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
16:15:26,329 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
16:15:26,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0119: Unbinding connection factory named java:/JmsXA to alias java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
16:15:26,498 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-5) AMQ151007: Resource adaptor started
16:15:26,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
16:15:26,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
16:15:26,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0118: Binding connection factory named java:/JmsXA to alias java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
16:15:26,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
16:15:26,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV00
```

MY standalone-full.xml

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:6.0">
  <server name="default">
    <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}" />
    <security-setting name="#">
      <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true" />
    </security-setting>
    <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" />
    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor" />
    <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
      <param name="batch-delay" value="50" />
    </http-connector>
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
      <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false" />
    </in-vm-connector>
    <remote-connector name="remote_conector" socket-binding="mqtt" />
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default" />
    <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
      <param name="batch-delay" value="50" />
      <param name="direct-deliver" value="false" />
    </http-acceptor>
    <remote-acceptor name="mqtt-acceptor" socket-binding="mqtt">
      <param name="protocols" value="MQTT" />
      <param name="batch-delay" value="50" />
      <param name="direct-deliver" value="true" />
    </remote-acceptor>
    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
      <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false" />
    </in-vm-acceptor>
    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue" />
    <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ" />
    <jms-queue name="test" entries="java:/jms/queue/test java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test" />
    <jms-topic name="test1" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/test1 java:/jms/topic/test1" />
    <jms-topic name="test2" entries="java:/jms/topic/test2 java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/test2" />
    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" />
    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" />
    <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa" />
  </server>



  <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}" />
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}" />
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}" />
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}" />
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}" />
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712" />
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713" />
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528" />
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529" />
    <socket-binding name="mqtt" port="1883" />
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
      <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25" />
    </outbound-socket-binding>
  </socket-binding-group>
```

My artemis/main/module.xml

```html
module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
<resources>
  <resource-root path="artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-selector-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-server-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-cli-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-dto-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-hqclient-protocol-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-jdbc-store-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-jms-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-jms-server-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-service-extensions-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-tools-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
  <resource-root path="artemis-mqtt-protocol-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />

</resources>

<dependencies>
  <module name="com.google.guava" />
  <module name="javax.api" />
  <module name="javax.jms.api" />
  <module name="javax.json.api" />
  <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" />
  <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal" export="true" />
  <module name="org.jboss.jts" />
  <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
  <module name="io.netty" />
  <module name="org.jgroups" />
  <module name="javax.resource.api" />
  <!-- WFLY-5213 Optional dependency to use the org.apache.activemq.artemis as a naming's external-context module -->
  <module name="org.jboss.invocation" optional="true" />
  <module name="org.jboss.jboss-transaction-spi" />
  <!--this reverse dependency is here so integration classes in the AS code base can be instantiated by Artemis-->
  <module name="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq" services="import" />
  <module name="org.jboss.as.security" />
  <module name="org.picketbox" />
  <!-- this optional dependency is required to be able to use this module from a jms-bridge to connect to a remote
             WildFly server [AS7-6549] -->
  <module name="org.wildfly.naming-client" optional="true" services="import" />
  <!-- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4936  this is to avoid an issue on IBM JDK -->
  <module name="sun.jdk" />
  <!-- supported protocols (in addition to the CORE protocol) -->
  <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp" services="import" optional="true" />
  <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.hornetq" services="import" optional="true" />
  <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.stomp" services="import" optional="true" />
  <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.mqtt" services="import" optional="true" />
</dependencies>
</module>
```

My artemis/protocol/mqtt/module.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.mqtt">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="artemis-mqtt-protocol-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar" />
    <resource-root path="netty-codec-4.1.34.Final.jar" />
    <resource-root path="netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar" />

  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="io.netty" />
    <module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

One month later.

After an in deep reading Apache Artemis user manual, and having carried out many tests and configurations on both, standalone and wildfly16 embedded, I have been able to run the Artemis in Wildfly with Mqtt support.

As I mentioned in my original question there was impossible to subscribe to a queue or topic from mqtt client, however it was possible to send messages to that queue/topic.

If you read the Artemis manual, the information regarding the subscriptions to queues or topics clearly explains how subscription and publishing it is carried out.

In Artemis there are addresses and queues. the topic concept does not exists.

If autocreate-address  and autocreate-queues is enabled, clients when publish will create the addresses and queues.

The clients when subscribe will create address and queues as well. If there is more than one subscribers each one will, create an queue attached to the address.

So when a client publish, sends messages to the address and Artemis routes the messages to the attached queues.

There are statics addresses and queues that are defined in broker.xml.

A client can subscribe to those static addresses and will create a dynamic queue each one to receive messages.

Or If the programmer desires can code the client so as to attached to a static queue defined in broker.xml by means of the fully qualified name.

```
broker.xml  static address and queue
 </address>
     <address name="test">
            <multicast>
               <queue name="T1" />
            </multicast>
    </address>

client, field for fully qualyfied name 
  private String topic = "test::T1";
```

So in conclusion if you want to subscribe to a Wildfly16 Artemis from a Mqtt client you should set the standalone-full.xml to allow autocreation of queues.

```
<address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" auto-create-queues="true" auto-delete-queues="true" auto-create-addresses="true" auto-delete-addresses="true"/>
```

And that is all, allow the clients to create their own queues attached to the addresses.

Thanks to Justin Beltram for the recommendations over Wildfly log. The log level in debug mode gave me the clue.

Now I will try to set SSL support for Artemis in Wildfly16

Rafael